# How to connect to h2 database with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and am trying to create an API that will be used to fetch information about employees. In my application.properties file I have:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:employees
```

In data.sql I have:

```
INSERT INTO employees(name, age) VALUES ( 'PersonOne', 39 );
INSERT INTO employees(name, age) VALUES ( 'PersonTwo', 23 );
INSERT INTO employees(name, age) VALUES ( 'PersonThree', 45 );

COMMIT;
```

Then I have created a RestRepository interface:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface RestRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

And an Employee class with these fields and some getters and setters:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Double age;

    *some getters and setters*
```

But I keep getting an error saying: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Edit: the whole error stack trace is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/noratomas/Documents/Tutorials/Spring%20Boot/demo/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO employees(name, age) VALUES ( 'PEersonOne', 39 ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "EMPLOYEES" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO employees(name, age) VALUES ( 'PersonOne', 39 ) [42102-199]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/noratomas/Documents/Tutorials/Spring%20Boot/demo/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO employees(name, age) VALUES ( 'PersonOne', 39 ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "EMPLOYEES" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO employees(name, age) VALUES ( 'PersonOne', 39 ) [42102-199]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:509) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:238) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:202) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:89) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:37) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:85) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:429) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "EMPLOYEES" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO employees(name, age) VALUES ( 'PersonOne', 39 ) [42102-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7146) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7117) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1682) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:891) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:788) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:760) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:683) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:627) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:565) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1292) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:217) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:488) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post the complete exception stack trace, please ?

Comment: Yes, I did that now, thank you for taking a look!

Comment: You should create Employee table before inserting data in it

Comment: No, you don't need to create it. Spring Boot is probably already doing that for you. You just need to remove the "s" from employee**s** at your INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the table you are trying to insert data into is called EMPLOYEES (with a "S") while your entity is called Employee.

Spring Boot is probably creating that table for you, but without the "S".

Try changing your INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the stack trace, it looks like your table doesn't exist. Before you insert data into it, there should be a table to do so. Create a scheme.sql and create your Employee table in it. If you are using H2 database it can also be created internally directly from your Employee class file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the tables in SQL?
if not, you should either create the tables manually for each entity or simply enable auto DDL using:
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`

Answer (score 0):

The table that Hibernate DDL is going to generate from your Entity will be named Employee not Employees

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting in EMPLOYEE**S**, whereas your entity is called EMPLOYEE.

If you want Hibernate to create EMPLOYEE**S**, you can add the `@Table` annotation on top of your Employee class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee
```